# How can I limit the size of temporary tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, temp-tables

I have largish (InnoDB) tables in a database; apparently the users are capable of making SELECTs with JOINs that result in temporary, large (and thus on-disk) tables. Sometimes, those are so large that they exhaust disk space, leading to all sorts of weird issues.

Is there a way to limit temp table maximum size *for an on-disk table*, so that the table doesn't overgrow the disk? [tmp_table_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) only applies to in-memory tables, despite the name. I haven't found anything relevant in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html).

Comment: Yes, *I* am aware that storage is cheap, and that the best solution would be "prevent the queries". However, those are not in the options which I currently have.

Comment: Some "huge" queries can be re-formulated to avoid large tmp tables.  Can you change the query?  If so, please provide `SELECT ...`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.  Shrinking the tmp table will _probably_ speed it up.

Comment: Here are the guidelines (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) that will help you optimize your queries.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that queries can be optimized (see my answers in `mysql` tag). Unfortunately, if the dataset is hundreds of GB and the queries are somewhat dynamically constructed, there's very few useful optimization that we haven't tried already. (Yes, I'm aware that big data warehousing is not a job for MySQL, and a better solution is in the works - looking for an interim workaround) Thank you for the link to documentation, will edit that into the question.

Answer (score 5):

There [was a discussion](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/19/tmp_table_size-and-max_heap_table_size/) about an option `disk-tmp-table-size`, but it looks like [the commit](https://lists.mysql.com/commits/15390) did not make it through review or got lost for some other reason ([at least the option does not exist in the current code base anymore](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/23032807537d8dd8ee4ec1c4d40f0633cd4e12f9/sql/sys_vars.cc)).

I guess your next best try (besides increasing storage) is to tune MySQL to not make on-disk temp tables. [There are some tips for this on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53201/34681). Another attempt could be to create a ramdisk for the storage of the "on-disk" temp tables, if you have enough RAM and only lack disk storage.

Comment: A lot can happen in 10+ years; I didn't find this option in any of my servers. Thank you for the in-RAM suggestion, but alas: for a 250 GB temp table, this is even less likely than "get a disk".

Comment: This seems to be the only option as of now. I too wasn't able to find more information about it.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. Hence the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

There's no option for this in MariaDB and MySQL. 
I ran into the same issue as you some months ago, I searched a lot and I finally partially solved it by creating a special storage area on the NAS for themporary datasets.

Create a folder on your NAS or a partition on an internal HDD, it will be by definition limited in size, then mount it, and in the mysql ini, assign the temporary storage to this drive:  (choose either windows/linux)

```
tmpdir="mnt/DBtmp/"
tmpdir="T:\"
```

mysql service should be restarted after this change.

With this approach, once the drive is full, you still have "weird issues" with on-disk queries, but the other issues are gone.

Comment: While not a full solution, this seems to be the only actionable workaround. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While it does not answer the question for MySQL, MariaDB has [tmp_disk_table_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#tmp_disk_table_size) and potentially also useful [max_join_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#max_join_size) settings. However, `tmp_disk_table_size` is only for MyISAM or Aria tables, not for InnoDB. Also, `max_join_size` works only on the estimated row count of the join, not the actual row count. On the bright side, the error is issued almost immediately.

Comment: Thank you, that could be useful!